# Show $\| X \| = \sqrt{X^* A X}$ is a norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, normed-spaces

I'm trying to show that, given a positive definite matrix $A\in \mathcal{M_n}(\mathbb{C})$, the function

$$\begin{array}{cccl}
\lVert \cdot \rVert: &\mathbb{C}^n &\longrightarrow &\mathbb{R}
\\\ &X &\longmapsto & \lVert X \rVert = \sqrt{X^* A X}
\end{array}$$

is a norm.

I've proved all properties except $\| X+Y \| \leq \| X \|+\| Y \| \ \forall \ X,Y \in  \mathbb{C}^n$.

$$\| X+Y \|= \sqrt{(X+Y)^* A (X+Y)}=\sqrt{(X^*+Y^*) A (X+Y)}=\sqrt{X^*AX+X^*AY+Y^*AX+Y^*AY}$$

$$\| X\| +\|Y \|= \sqrt{X^* A X} + \sqrt{Y^* A Y}$$

I don't know how to arrive to the inequality from here.

Comment: You'll want to make use of the fact that $A$ is positive definite and thus has a Cholesky factorization.

Comment: In my opinion, diagonalization provides a more natural decomposition $A = Q \lambda Q^*$ in that you can visualize how the metric scales each axis

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can instead show that 
$$
\langle x,y\rangle_A:=x^*Ay,\quad x,y\in{\bf C}^n,
$$
is an [inner product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space), which implies that $x\mapsto\sqrt{\langle x,x\rangle_A}$ defines a norm.

Essentially, the triangle inequality is a consequence of the [Cauchy-Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality).  Note that in your calculation, taking the square makes things easier:
$$
\|X+Y\|^2= (X+Y)^* A (X+Y)
=(X^*+Y^*) A (X+Y)
=X^*AX+X^*AY+Y^*AX+Y^*AY,
$$
$$
(\| X\| +\|Y \|)^2
= X^* A X + Y^* A Y +2\|X\|\cdot\|Y\|.
$$

Now to show the triangle inequality, it suffices to show that
$$
2\|X\|\cdot\|Y\|\geqslant X^*AY+Y^*AX.
$$
But since $A$ is Hermitian, 
$$
X^*AY+Y^*AX=X^*AY+X^*AY=2X^*AY.
$$
So you want to show
$$
\|X\|\cdot\|Y\|\geqslant X^*AY,
$$
which is a consequence of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality.

Answer (score 1):

You can get an eigenbasis diagonalization of $A$ as  $A = Q \lambda Q^*$

Do the change of variables $\hat X = \lambda^{-1/2} Q^*X$.

$$||X + Y|| = ||\hat X + \hat Y||_2 \le ||\hat X||_2 + ||\hat Y||_2 = ||X|| + ||Y||$$